# How to import files from external folders during android app runtime

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, asset-pipeline, assets

I'm looking to create a model viewer for android. I'd like to be able to pull in whatever .obj files are in a specific external, nonbundled folder to view in the application. What is the best way to go about this? so far i have looked at asset bundles and the addressable asset system, but i'm not sure if either of them can pull from stuff not already in the unity editor.

basically i'd like to drag and drop models into a folder on the device where i can load them during app runtime, without having to prep them in unity first. Anyone have any advice or examples i could take a look at?

Edit: OBJimporter will not suit my needs, as it my models will often hit the vertice limit, as well as it seems it may be outdated being from 4 years ago.

Answer (score 0):

If your models are going to have more that 65k vertices then it's, probably, impossible to load them in Unity.
There is also a reason why Unity does not have runtime loader from 3d model file. You either will use assetbundles or use workaround solutions and getting a lot of pain.
For example you can try this https://assetstore.unity.com/packages/tools/modeling/trilib-model-loader-package-91777, have fun.